# What's considered more painful? ache Vs. painful Vs. sore

Tags: word-difference

What's considered more painful of the following three words? I saw on the dictionary that all of the following three words: **[ache](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ache?q=aching), [painful](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/painful)** and **[sore](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sore)** have the same meaning and it's not clear to me if they're just synonyms or they have some subtle differences. (I know that "ache", unlike sore and painful, is a noun rather than an adjective, but still the difference between I'd like to know if there is a difference in the meaning.)

Examples:

> * She's got a **sore back**. Vs. She's got a **backache** Vs. She's got a **painful back**.
>
> * All the dust has made my **eyes sore**. Vs. All the dust has made my **eyes painful**. Vs. All the dust cause to my eyes to (be) ache.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare the three in terms of which is worse pain. If you want to do that you have to describe the pain with an adjective. A 'searing' pain is worse than a 'minor' pain. A 'throbbing' headache is worse than a 'little' headache.

All three mean 'pain', which makes them synonyms in a sense. But they can't be used interchangeably. Each one might be used more often than another in a given situation, but which one is used can depend on the person speaking or the local custom where they live.

What makes it even harder is that pain is a subjective feeling. One person's ache might be another person's soreness. The word 'pain' doesn't even mean the same thing all the time.